# Android communicating with web server data

Tags: android

I am writing a android application to read a php script in my LAMP server which display the data inside mysql database. The php script simply fetches all rows inside my database table.

I would like to ask if there is any method to parse the information of the php script and set the textview inside the application with the information fetched.

Should my php script echo the data in text, array or JSON format?
What methods or direction should I follow to fetch and parse the data into my android application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that JSON is the best format to use, as there are good JSON libraries around .

If you use a JSON library such as Gson or Jackson you can have the library map the JSON recieved from your php script to a Java domain class. So the library will parse the JSON and create an instance of your Java class for you.

Then it is easy to fill your textview with the values from your java object.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer gives the details about what you may do in your app to parse the JSON data  . I would like to add more details regarding how you can create the JSON object inside your php files . You may use the `json_encode` php function to convert the data that you get from your database into a JSON format .

[PHP json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) official documentation with exampes